# How to flatten nested array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

As we know, to flatten the array `[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]` by using the method `reduce()`

```
var flattened = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]].reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b);
});
```

So how to flatten this array `[[[0], [1]], [[2], [3]], [[4], [5]]]` to `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`?

Comment: See this discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: [[[0], [1]], [[2], [3]], [[4], [5]]].toString().split(",").map(Number);

Comment: @dandavis this is black magic. What if he has strings or other types? :D

Comment: @LeoDeng: i didn't see any strings, and other methods would be too complicated to fit in a comment...

Comment: @dandavis I mean, he was just taking 12345 for an example, I assume. Essentially I think it should be a recursion. The code he posted was from this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Example:_Flatten_an_array_of_arrays

Comment: The same code you've posted is working on nested array of any depth.

Comment: @deekshith, `[[[0], [1]], [[2], [3]], [[4], [5]]].reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b);
});` just return `[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]`, rather than `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: @zangw Thats strange. I've tried it just now on Firefox 46 Dev edition and Chrome 48 and it returns `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` for me. Try this: http://www.es6fiddle.com/ikt0pffy/

Comment: @deekshith, I test it under Chrome console. it give the result as I mentioned before. I am not sure why es6fiddle give that result...it is weird... maybe bug

Comment: This SO question is the answer for this bonfire on Free Code Camp: https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/steamroller

Comment: This question is definitely not a duplicate, as this one addresses more than one level of depth

Comment: `const arr = [1, 2, '22',[1,33,44,['ddd'], 5678], 'abbb', 'ccc', 1234];`

`const flat = String(arr).split(',').map((elm)=>  {`

    `return  !isNaN(elm) ? Number(elm) : elm`
    
`})`
`console.log(flat)`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is an alternative to recursion (**[see jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/axelduch/44tgert8/)**) and should accept any level of depth which avoids stack overflow.

```js
var array = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5, [6, 7, [8, [9, 10]]]]];
console.log(flatten(array), array); // does not mutate array
console.log(flatten(array, true), array); // array is now empty

// This is done in a linear time O(n) without recursion
// memory complexity is O(1) or O(n) if mutable param is set to false
function flatten(array, mutable) {
    var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
    var arrayTypeStr = '[object Array]';
    
    var result = [];
    var nodes = (mutable && array) || array.slice();
    var node;

    if (!array.length) {
        return result;
    }

    node = nodes.pop();
    
    do {
        if (toString.call(node) === arrayTypeStr) {
            nodes.push.apply(nodes, node);
        } else {
            result.push(node);
        }
    } while (nodes.length && (node = nodes.pop()) !== undefined);

    result.reverse(); // we reverse result to restore the original order
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `Object.prototype.toString.call(node) == '[object Array]'` instead of `Array.isArray(node)`?

Comment: It's just for ie8 and below

Comment: sneaky using apply in there to split the arr, love it.

Comment: Why not use instanceof operator instead of toString?

if (node instanceof Array) {
  nodes.push.apply(nodes, node);
} else {
  result.push(node);
}

Comment: You could do that too, yes. Matter of taste at this point

Comment: @axelduch may i (or someone else) turn this into a module (npm etc.)?

Comment: You are free to use the code as you wish, and even though it is probably debatable to turn this into a module on its own, since it is more a helper than a complete module I would not try to go against it. Cheers :)

Comment: If it avoids Stack Overflow, why is it here?

Comment: This is great, however it seems like if `mutable` is true, just simple the single line `var nodes = (mutable && array) || array.slice();` seems to perform a _deep_ copy of the array passed to the function. How/why is this possible!?

Comment: Would `nodes = [...nodes, ...node]` also leave the elements in place, so would keep memory consumption O(1) without using the slightly obscure `apply` syntax? (Appreciate this answer was written long before we got `...` - just curious whether I understand this properly.)

Answer (score 73):

Perfect use case for recursion, which could handle even deeper structure:

```
function flatten(ary) {
    var ret = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
        if(Array.isArray(ary[i])) {
            ret = ret.concat(flatten(ary[i]));
        } else {
            ret.push(ary[i]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

flatten([[[[[0]], [1]], [[[2], [3]]], [[4], [5]]]]) // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Alternatively, as an Array method:

```
Array.prototype.flatten = function() {
    var ret = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if(Array.isArray(this[i])) {
            ret = ret.concat(this[i].flatten());
        } else {
            ret.push(this[i]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
};

[[[[[0]], [1]], [[[2], [3]]], [[4], [5]]]].flatten() // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

---

EDIT #1: Well, think it a little bit functional way (except for the named recursion which should be using Y-combinator for pure functional :D).

```
function flatten(ary) {
  return ary.reduce(function(a, b) {
    if (Array.isArray(b)) {
      return a.concat(flatten(b))
    }
    return a.concat(b)
  }, [])
}
```

Let's adopt some ES6 syntax which makes it even shorter, in one line.

```
const flatten = (ary) => ary.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(Array.isArray(b) ? flatten(b) : b), [])
```

But remember, this one cannot be applied as an array method, because [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) don't have theirs own `this`.

---

EDIT #2: With the latest `Array.prototype.flat` proposal this is super easy. The array method accepts an optional parameter `depth`, which specifies how deep a nested array structure should be flattened (default to `1`).

```
[[[[[0]], [1]], [[[2], [3]]], [[4], [5]]]].flat()  // [[[[0]], [1]], [[[2], [3]]], [[4], [5]]]
[[[[[0]], [1]], [[[2], [3]]], [[4], [5]]]].flat(2) // [[[0]], [1], [[2], [3]], [4], [5]]
[[[[[0]], [1]], [[[2], [3]]], [[4], [5]]]].flat(3) // [[0], 1, [2], [3], 4, 5]
[[[[[0]], [1]], [[[2], [3]]], [[4], [5]]]].flat(4) // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

So to flatten an array of arbitrary depth, just call `flat` method with `Infinity`.

```
[[[[[0]], [1]], [[[2], [3]]], [[4], [5]]]].flat(Infinity) // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This could be made a bit faster by reusing the `ret` array. See my answer for such an solution.

Comment: isn't this n^2? `concat` is not a constant time operation. It's a O(n) operation AFAIK.

Answer (score 53):

<s>ES6-style with recursion:</s>

```
Redacted
```

---

**June 2018 Update:**

There is now an ES proposal for an [`Array.prototype.flat` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat). It is currently at stage 3, meaning it's likely to be implemented by browsers soon(ish) and make it into the spec in its current form. There are probably some polyfills floating around.

Example:

```
const nested = [[[0], [1]], [[2], [3]], [[4], [5]]];
const flattened = nested.flat(2);  // Need to specify depth if > 1
```

**June 2019 Update:**

`Array.prototype.flat` was officially added to the language in the ES2019 spec.

Comment: Good practice for ES6

Comment: any draw back to calling this method with infinity as the other answer suggests? we don't always know the depth of the array.

Comment: @AngelaP It's designed to be used like that, however in practice it seems there's a limit to how deep the array can go. After testing, for me in Chrome that limit seems to be 7387 - any more and it will throw a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error. I'm also able to flatten an array with a circular reference (i.e. infinitely recursive) up to that limit - in other words `.flat(7387)` works but `.flat(7388)` throws the same error. Other browsers/engines may behave differently, but if the arrays you're operating on are anywhere near that deep I think you have bigger issues.

Answer (score 39):

[ES2019 solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```
ary.flat(Infinity);
```

That's it. It's that simple. You can change `Infinity` to be the appropriate level of flattenedness if you wish.

Example:

```js
console.log([[[0], [1]], [[2], [3]], [[4], [5]]].flat(Infinity));
```

Other, longer solutions that work with [older browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=array-flat) below.

---

Based on @Leo's solution, but faster by reusing the same array and preventing `.concat`

```js
function flatten(ary, ret = []) {
    for (const entry of ary) {
        if (Array.isArray(entry) {
            flatten(entry, ret);
        } else {
            ret.push(entry);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
console.log(flatten([[[0], [1]], [[2], [3]], [[4], [5]]]));
```

Or with `Array.prototype.reduce`, since you mentioned it:

```js
function flatten(ary, ret = []) {
    return ary.reduce((ret, entry) => {
        if (Array.isArray(entry)) {
            flatten(entry, ret);
        } else {
            ret.push(entry);
        }
        return ret;
    }, ret);
}
console.log(flatten([[[0], [1]], [[2], [3]], [[4], [5]]]));
```

Comment: Probably the best and most readable solution out here

Comment: Much, much, much better answer than most here. There's no good reason at all for all of the temporary arrays floating around the other answers.

Comment: @timothygu can you explain how will you describe time and space complexity of both solutions in Big-O Notation?

Comment: @baltusaj Asymptotic analysis is pretty much useless for this specific case, since all solutions in this question follow essentially the same algorithm. It's about the constant terms (like creation of an empty array) that differentiate this solution from the rest.

Comment: This is still slower than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 16):

ES6 one-liner:

```
function flatten(a) {
    return Array.isArray(a) ? [].concat(...a.map(flatten)) : a;
}
```

Also, non-recursive version for very deep arrays (not very efficient but rather elegant)

```
function flatten(a) {
    var queue = a.slice();
    var result = [];
    while(queue.length) {
        let curr = queue.pop();
        if(Array.isArray(curr)) {
            queue.push(...curr);
        }
        else result.push(curr);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You ES6 one-liner looks very nice but can you add explanation about how is it working exactly?

Comment: @baltusaj it's a recursive solution. If the current element is not an array, return it. If it is, flatten every element of the array (using Array.map) and then concatenate the resulting arrays (using Array.concat and spreading the array to function parameters)

Comment: thanks. I guess the "spreading" is done by the three dots.

Comment: more es6 magic: let flatten = a => Array.isArray(a) ? [].concat(...a.map(flatten)) : a;

Comment: the second implementation failed [my tests](https://codepen.io/mindplay-dk/pen/EbeVGP)

Comment: @matanso your non recursive solution is printing the array in reverse order, instead on queue.pop() if you use queue.shift() it will work fine as expected.

Answer (score 8):

Flattens 2 levels only:

```
var arr = [1, [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]];
[].concat.apply([], arr) // -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 5):

This is already answered but I am just studying JS and wonder what about:

```
    var array = [[[0], [1]], [[2], [3]], [[4], [5]]];
    var flattend = array.join(",").split(",");
    console.log(flattend);
```

Only side affect is that the join converts all items to strings, but that can be easilly fixed

Comment: For numbers and strings this solution is pretty intelligent, but the problem becomes more complicated when objects and functions are involved.

Comment: I was looking for easy solution to use on strings arrays. This one is perfect.

Answer (score 5):

I like my solution :)

```
var flattenClosure = function(a) {
    var store = [];

    return function() {
        var internMapper = function(b) {
            if (Array.isArray(b)) {
                return b.map(internMapper);
            }
            store.push(b);
            return b;
        }
        a.map(internMapper);
        return store;
    }
};

console.log(flattenClosure([[[[[[[[1]]]], [2], [4], [6, 8, 9], 2]]], 10, 11, [15, 17, 20], [], 33])());
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're aware the array is made up of only numbers you can just do the following:

```
array.join().split(',').map(Number);
```

Comment: answered an interview question with something like this.  Not sure the humor was appreciated... lol

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by code from [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) and the answer provided by @axelduch (A lot more efficient from what I can tell too.)

```
function flatten(array, mutable) {
  var nodes = (mutable && array) || array.slice(); // return a new array.
  var flattened = [];

  for (var node = nodes.shift(); node !== undefined; node = nodes.shift()) {
    if (Array.isArray(node)) {
      nodes.unshift.apply(nodes, node);
    } else {
      flattened.push(node);
    }
  }

  return flattened;
}
```

Comment: These solutions need more upvotes, the usage of apply is so clutch for efficiency.

Comment: looks like the original by @axelduch [is faster](https://codepen.io/mindplay-dk/pen/EbeVGP)

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer**: I know that it is an old and already answered question, but @Nick has got me into it as I have commented his answer as *one of the most expensive way to flatten an array*. I haven't been coding JavaScript for years, but it's like riding a bike - once you learn you'll never forget ;)

Here is my full recursive code (no `for` loop needed):

```
var flattened = [];
function flatten(a, i) {
    if(a.length > i) {
        if(Array.isArray(a[i]))
            flatten(a[i], 0);
        else
            flattened.push(a[i]);
        flatten(a, i + 1);
    }
}

flatten([[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]], 0);
console.log(flattened);
```

I have tested it against `toString().split(',')` solution and mine is about 7 times faster. That's what I mean when talking about *expensiveness* ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
function flatten(array) {
    return array.reduce(
        (previous, current) =>
            Array.isArray(current)
            ? [...previous, ...flatten(current)]
            : [...previous, current]
        , []
    );
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

```
var nested = [[[0], [1]], [[2], [3]], [[4], [5]]];
var flattened = [].concat.apply([],[].concat.apply([],nested));
console.log('-> flattened now: ' + flattened);
```

Comment: if we change `nested` to `[[[0], [[1]]], [[2], [3]], [[4], [5]]]` it would flatten everything... also when printing, cannot use `+` or else some debugger might print out by flattening things for you, need to use a `,` instead

Comment: This solution limits the depth to at most three levels. For example, `[[[[4]]]]` will return `[[4]]` rather than `[4]`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [dashamble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2939570/dashambles)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35187235/1050556), but I believe this is a bit simpler to understand:

```
var steamroller = function(arr) {
  var result = [];

  var dropHeavyObject = function(auxArr) {
    var flatnd = [];

    flatnd = auxArr.map(function(x) {
      if(Array.isArray(x)) {
        return dropHeavyObject(x);
      } else {
        result.push(x);
        return x;
      }
    });

    return flatnd;
  };

  dropHeavyObject(arr);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are three utility functions in lodash related to your question [`flatten`, `flattenDeep`, flattenDepth](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten) in `lodash`. `flatten` goes into a single depth, `flattenDeep` goes all the way into the deepest level and flattenDepth gives you the choice of "how deep" to flatten.

**Example:**

```
> var arr = [[[0], [1]], [[2], [3]], [[4], [5]]];
> _.flattenDeep(arr)
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var flattenWithStack = function(arr) {
  var stack = [];
  var flat = [];
  stack.push(arr);
  while(stack.length > 0) {
    var curr = stack.pop();
    if(curr instanceof Array) {
      stack = stack.concat(curr);
    } else {
      flat.push(curr);
    }
  }
  return flat.reverse();
}
```

Non recursive. Basically dfs.

Comment: Question has been answered years ago already. Please use comments instead to add your suggestions. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Terribly slow method

Answer (score 1):

```
function flatten(x) {
  if (x.length == 0) {return []};
  if (Array.isArray(x[0])) {
    return flatten(x[0].concat(flatten(x.slice(1,x.length))));
  }
  return [].concat([x[0]], flatten(x.slice(1,x.length)));
}
```

recursively flattens the array.

Comment: Cannot handle deeper structure though, `flatten([[[[[0]], [1]], [[[2], [3]]], [[4], [5]]]])` returns `[1, 4, 5, 0, 2, 3]`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I edited my answer to provide a solution that preserves element order (which is similar to your excellent solution).

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue the other day and discovered a little hack... actually I just realized it's very similar to the last answer and like comment to the above answer indicates, it won't work for objects, but for simple numbers etc. it works just fine.

If you take a nested array to string, it separates the values by commas. Then you can split it by commas to form a string. If you then need to convert the strings to int or float, you can run through the new array converting each value.

```
stringArray = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]].toString().split(',');
stringArray.forEach((v,i,a) => a[i] = parseFloat(a[i]));
```

Comment: I think that's one of the most expensive way to flatten an array.

Comment: Thanks, Adam. I'm a newbie, and was experimenting with the functions when I discovered this cheat ;) How do you estimate expense?

Comment: Heh, you've got me into this question ;) Please, take a look at my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Good news is I learned how to do it recursively shortly after I posted the newbie hack above, and it's (using recursion) so easy it's really not worth doing it another way. I see what you mean by expense!

Answer (score 1):

## An implementation with functional programming

With functional programming we can simply derive `flatten` from another more generic function: `traverse`.

The latter is a function to traverse and reduce arbitrarily nested arrays just like flat arrays. This is possible because nested arrays with unknown depth are no more than a particular version of a tree data structure:

```js
const traverse = f => g => acc => xs => {
  let [leaf, stack] = xs[0][0] === undefined
   ? [xs[0], xs.slice(1)]
   : f([]) (xs);

  return stack.length
   ? traverse(f) (g) (g(leaf) (acc)) (stack)
   : g(leaf) (acc);
};

const dfs = stack => tree => tree[0] === undefined 
 ? [tree, stack]
 : dfs(tree.length > 1 ? concat(stack) (tree.slice(1)) : stack) (tree[0]);

const concat = ys => xs => xs.concat(ys);
const flatten = f => traverse(f) (concat) ([]);

const xs = [[[1,2,3],4,5,6],7,8,[9,10,[11,12],[[13]],14],15];

console.log(flatten(dfs) (xs));
```

Please note that tree data structures can either be traversed by depth first (DFS) or by breadth first (BFS). Arrays are usually traversed in depth first order.

As I said `traverse` is a generic reduction function like reduce for flat arrays. So we can easily calculate the sum of all elements as well:

```
const add = y => x => x + y;
traverse(dfs) (add) (0) (xs); // 120
```

**Conclusion:** To flatten an arbitrarily nested array in a functional way we just need a one-liner: `const flatten = f => traverse(f) (concat) ([]);`. All other involved functions are generic and have a whole range of other potential applications. This is 100% reusability!

Answer (score 1):

Using `JSON.stringify` and  `JSON.parse`

```
arr = JSON.parse("[" + 
               JSON.stringify(arr)
                   .replace(/[\[\]]+/g,"")
                   .replace(/,,/g,",") +
               "]");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Lisp conventions.

Using .shift() and .concat() is inefficient, however.

```
    flatten (array) {

        // get first element (car) and shift array (cdr) 
        var car = array.shift();

        // check to see if array was empty
        if (car === undefined) {
            return [];

        // if the first element (car) was an array, recurse on it
        } else if (_.isArray(car)) {
            return flatten(car).concat(flatten(array));

        // otherwise, cons (concatenate) the car to the flattened version of cdr (rest of array)
        } else {
            return [car].concat(flatten(array))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// implementation
function flattenArray(){
  const input = arguments[0]
      , output = flatten(input)

  function flatten(){
    return [].concat.apply([], arguments[0])
  }

  return input.length === output.length
    ? output
    : flattenArray(output)
}

// how to use?
flattenArray([1,2,[3]) // return [1,2,3]
```

Test Cases ->
https://github.com/CHAOWEICHIU/ccw-custom-functions/blob/master/test/units/flattenArray.js

Answer (score 1):

```
function flatten(arrayOfArrays) {
  return arrayOfArrays.reduce(function(flat, subElem) {
    return flat.concat(Array.isArray(subElem) ? flatten(subElem) : subElem);
  }, []);
}


var arr0 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var arr1 = [[0,1], 2, [3, 4]];
var arr2 = [[[0, 1], 2], 3, 4];
console.log(flatten(arr0));  // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(flatten(arr1));  // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(flatten(arr2));  // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(flatten([]));    // []
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an **infinitely** nested array like `a` below, here's what I'd do.

```
const a = [[1,2,[3]],4]

Array.prototype.flatten = (array) => {
  const newArray = []
  const flattenHelper = (array) => {
    array.map(i => {
      Array.isArray(i) ? flattenHelper(i) : newArray.push(i)
    })
  }
  flattenHelper(a)
  return newArray
}

const newArray = a.flatten()
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I've got:

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  // the flattened array
  var newArr = [];

  // recursive function
  function flatten(arr, newArr) {
    // go through array
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      // if element i of the current array is a non-array value push it
      if (Array.isArray(arr[i]) === false) {
        newArr.push(arr[i]);
      }
      // else the element is an array, so unwrap it
      else {
        flatten(arr[i], newArr);
      }
    }
  }

  flatten(arr, newArr);

  return newArr;
}
```

Comment: This will flatten only nested arrays and not linear arrays. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved like this

```
const array = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5, [6, 7, [8, [9, 10]]]]];

const flatten(arr) => arr.reduce((acc, item) => 
   acc.concat(Array.isArray(item) ? flatten(item) : item);
}, []);

console.log(flatten(array));
```

Be aware that in case of the deep arrays, the TCO should be applied

The version with the TCO with the recursion solution

```
const array = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5, [6, 7, [8, [9, 10]]]]];

const flatten = (() => {
  const _flatten = (acc, arr) => arr.reduce((acc, item) =>  acc.concat(Array.isArray(item) ? _flatten([], item) : item), acc);

  return arr => _flatten([], arr);
})();

console.log(flatten(array))
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this function works.

```
 function flatten(arr){
     return arr.reduce(function(a,b){
        return [].concat(Array.isArray(a)? flatten(a) :a,Array.isArray(b)? flatten(b):b);
      });

}
```