# Javascript: How to spread a array element to all other element and make a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array like

```
var arr = [["one", "two"],["three", "four"],["five", "six", "seven"],["eight", "nine"]];
```

I am trying to make all the elements unite the elements, but the elements in the same sub-array must not replicate. like:

```
var output = ["one three four five six seven eight nine","two three four five six seven eight nine"];
```

This will be added based on number of elements in the first sub array.
I tried it but couldn't find any solution. Can anyone help.?
This is my code i tried :

```
function big_for( data ){
    var aj = [];
    var k = 0;
    for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){
        for( var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++ ){
            aj[k] = data[i][j];
            k++;
        } 
    }
    return arr;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: might be duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266550/how-to-flatten-nested-array-in-javascript

Comment: Does it then go "three one two four five six seven eight nine"? If not I don't see the correlation between your input and your expected output.

Comment: You can flatten your array. this might be the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-a-multidimensional-array-in-javascript

Comment: @RafaelGrillo, look at the expected output. A simple flatten is not the answer.

Comment: The output must be 1st sub array's element with all other elements. Therfore number of array in output will the count of first sub array. Got it.?

Comment: So is this for some sort of coding test or something? Don't really see what business case this would be needed for.

Comment: @David custom filter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry @Andy

```
var arr = [["one", "two"],["three", "four"],["five", "six", "seven"],["eight", "nine"]];

var base = arr.shift();
var result = base.map(function(init) {
    return [].concat.apply([], [init].concat(arr)).join(' ');
});
```

Comment: Oh I haven't used `shift` and `concat` before. Can you explain both. Oh ya this worked.! Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

Shift will remove the first element of the array and return it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat
Concat will simply concatenate a array with another array

Comment: What if I need second array to be in gendral.? Now the first is in gendral.