# recursive approach to nested arrays without using .concat or .reduce in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm working on a simple recursive approach to flattening arrays, and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. I've seen other threads on this ([How to flatten nested array in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266550/how-to-flatten-nested-array-in-javascript)) but I'm trying to do it without using .concat or .reduce.

This one keeps looping, but I'm not sure why- looks like it should hit the most nested array and return whatever characters within it.

Thanks!

```
var ret= [];
var nested = [['a','b'],[],'c',['d','e']];
function flatten(arr) {
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      flatten(arr[i]);
    } else {
        ret.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
}
flatten(nested);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to declare `i` as a variable. It is being treated as a global variable.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
```

If you output the value of `i` in each iteration you will see your infinite loop problem,

```
0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, ...
```

Comment: That only explains part of the problem.  The recursion causes later invocations of `flatten` to reuse that same global variable and overwrite the value in it while the loops in the outer invocations are still in the middle of iterating.

Comment: Andrew that did it! I don't think RJM's comment is true, as it works with the addition of 'var' in the for loop. Thanks all! Appreciate the help

Comment: @skdfsdfa, RJM is correct in their explanation of the issue. They were trying to add more context as to the reason **why** your code is causing an infinite loop.

Comment: I see, I thought they were specifying a separate issue instead of adding more context. Thanks again, this makes a lot more sense now