# JS get all the arrays within an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object that looks like the following:

```
const test = {
  leagues: [
    {
      timezone: "GMT",
      date: "1/2/2",
      premierLeague: [
        { name: "Liverpool", age: 1892 },
        { name: "Manchester Utd", age: 1878 }
      ],
      laLiga: [
        {
          team: "Real Madrid",
          stadium: "Bernabeu"
        },
        {
          team: "Barcelona",
          stadium: "Camp Nou"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

and I want the result to look like

```
const result = [
  { name: "Liverpool", age: 1892 },
  { name: "Manchester Utd", age: 1878 },
  {
    team: "Real Madrid",
    stadium: "Bernabeu"
  },
  {
    team: "Barcelona",
    stadium: "Camp Nou"
  }
];
```

I have tried to use [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) but am having trouble getting the arrays within the `leagues`. The result will be dynamic so I need to be able to get all the arrays within `leagues`. Can anyone point me in the correct direction to do this?

Comment: Do you really want that result? It's objects of totally different shapes in the same array. Don't do that.

Comment: I know it's not ideal, but it is what I need

Comment: Check the solutions here, it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266550/how-to-flatten-nested-array-in-javascript

Comment: @Evren Not sure how that can help, please be more specific how you think it will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for

```
const result = test.leagues.flatMap(league =>
  Object.values(league).filter(Array.isArray).flat()
);
```

Comment: thanks for this, but as  I said the response will be dynamic so can't hard code names of the arrays

Comment: @peterflanagan Oh I thought you would know the structure, and only the values in the arrays would be dynamic… but if you don't know the names of array-valued properties I have updated my answer. It still assumes `test.leagues` to be an array of objects with possibly-array-valued properties, is that right? Not arbitrarily nested?

Answer (score 3):

If your object structure doesn't go an deeper than that, this long one-liner should work:

```js
const result = test.leagues.reduce((arr, obj) => Object.values(val).reduce((innerArr, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? innerArr.concat(val) : innerArr, arr), []);
```

Somewhat ungolfed:

```js
const result = test.leagues.reduce((arr, obj) => {
  return Object.values(val).reduce((innerArr, val) => {
    return Array.isArray(val)
      ? innerArr.concat(val) 
      : innerArr
  }, arr);
}), []);
```

Comment: Mixing `reduce` with `forEach` and `push` is quite ugly, don't you think?

Comment: @Bergi you're not wrong. I fired that off between meetings

Comment: Thanks! I'd still prefer @Juan's `for`+`push` or my `flatMap` over `reduce`, but at least it's consistent now :-)

Comment: I almost deleted my answer since I saw this and @Bergi's . I still posted it in because the double loop is the easiest one to scan and quickly know what is happening. I do know it is not as elegant 

Comment: @JuanMendes don't sweat it. Elegant is a matter of degrees.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds weird, you'll end up with objects of different shapes in the same array. I'm not sure how you'll deal with that.

It looks like you're trying to concatenate every value of `test.leagues` that is itself an array.

```js
const test = {
  leagues: [{
    timezone: "GMT",
    date: "1/2/2",
    premierLeague: [{
        name: "Liverpool",
        age: 1892
      },
      {
        name: "Manchester Utd",
        age: 1878
      }
    ],
    laLiga: [{
        team: "Real Madrid",
        stadium: "Bernabeu"
      },
      {
        team: "Barcelona",
        stadium: "Camp Nou"
      }
    ]
  }]
};


const output = [];
for (const league of test.leagues) {
  for (const key in league) {
    if (Array.isArray(league[key])) {
      // Push each element in `league[key]` onto `output`
      // so we don't have to flatten it later
      output.push(...league[key]);
    }
  }
}
console.log({
  output
});
```

Comment: this isn't actually what I want. It should be a flat array

Comment: @peterflanagan Fixed by spreading the arrays as we push them: `output.push(...league[key]);`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm also adding my 2 cents over here. I do agree with everyone else. See if this works:

```js
const test = {
  leagues: [
    {
      timezone: "GMT",
      date: "1/2/2",
      premierLeague: [
        { name: "Liverpool", age: 1892 },
        { name: "Manchester Utd", age: 1878 }
      ],
      laLiga: [
        {
          team: "Real Madrid",
          stadium: "Bernabeu"
        },
        {
          team: "Barcelona",
          stadium: "Camp Nou"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

let finalArray = [];

function recursiveArr(obj, arrayToPush) {
    for(const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if(Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
      arrayToPush.push(obj[key]);
      continue;
    }
    
    const type = typeof obj[key];
    
    if(type === "object") {
       recursiveArr(obj[key], arrayToPush);
    }
  }
}

recursiveArr(test.leagues, finalArray);

console.log(finalArray.flat())
```