how to check how many [] symbols array contain
So, I have an array like this
const array=[1,2,3,4,[5,6],[[[[7,8]]]]]. I know that I can make it flat by flat function like this.
array.flat(4) // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
But as you know we can to this when we know array external count of this [] symbols. However we can fetch
any data that we don't know how many [] this symbols are there in array. My question is that how to check
how many [] - this symbols are there within array.

.flat(Infinity)

See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/27266550/3001761 - note asking about counting brackets is a classic XY problem, you care about the depth.

Does this answer your question? How to flatten nested array in javascript?

You can flatten an array of unknown depth with
array.flat(Infinity).length

You can count elements yourself though with a loop and a stack without recursion (no maximum call stack size error), that would be more efficient since you don't create a new array:


console.log(countNestedArrayItems([1,2,3,4,[5,6],[[[[7,8]]]]]));

function countNestedArrayItems(arr) {

    let count = 0;
    const path = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        const item = arr[i];

        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            path.push(arr, i);
            i = -1;
            arr = item;
            continue;
        }

        count++;
        while(i === arr.length - 1 && path.length)  i = path.pop(), arr = path.pop();

    }

    return count;

}



And a benchmark:
` Chrome/124
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>              n=6       |       n=60        |       n=600       |      n=6000     
count    ■ 1.00x x1m 116 | ■ 1.00x x100k  94 | ■ 1.00x x100k 927 | ■ 1.00x x10k 860
flat()     1.75x x1m 203 |   2.17x x100k 204 |   2.29x  x10k 212 |   2.60x  x1k 224
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `



const $chunk = [1,2,3,4,[5,6],[[[[7,8,[1,2,3,4,[5,6],[[[[7,8]]]]]]]]]];
const $input = [];

function countNestedArrayItems(arr) {

    let count = 0;
    const path = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        const item = arr[i];

        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            path.push(arr, i);
            i = -1;
            arr = item;
            continue;
        }

        count++;
        while(i === arr.length - 1 && path.length)  i = path.pop(), arr = path.pop();

    }

    return count;

}
// @benchmark count
countNestedArrayItems($input);

// @benchmark flat()
$input.flat(Infinity).length;

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));




Your question is not very clear, does this help?


const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6], [[[[7, 8]]]]];

function countNestedArrays(arr) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      count++;
      count += countNestedArrays(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(countNestedArrays(array));



